# How to disable all mouse events except for hover for iFrame?

Tags: css, reactjs, iframe

I would like to embed an iFrame in a React application.
Because of specific behavior of the external view being referenced in the iframe, I would like to disable everything with the exception of hover events, which must propagate through to the iframe.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe src="https://localhost:8022" height="600" width="800"></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried using the CSS property, pointer-events, in various ways, but have
not been successful. Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to accomplish this, I think the best you can do is to put a transparent div over the Iframe but this will not let any mouse events to work.

Comment: You can set the `pointer-events: none` CSS property, although that will also stop hover

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2019, this cannot be done I've determined.